# Can I give TidyHTML a string instead of a file?

Tags: tidy, htmltidy

I want to "beautify" a string from within a program I am developing with running it through TidyHTML. I was wondering if it is possible to pass to tidy just the string, or does it have to be a file?

It would save me from having to store the string to a file, tidy it, delete the file, and then put it inside the new file that I want to save :)

I was thinking of something like:

```
$ tidy '<html>.....</html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this once, you can use [HTML Tidy Online](http://infohound.net/tidy/) or [Dirty Markup](http://www.dirtymarkup.com/) to clean up your string.

Otherwise, according to the tidy [man](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html), you should be able to pass in your string from standard input.

> If no input file is specified, Tidy reads the standard input. If no
>   output file is specified, Tidy writes the tidied markup to the
>   standard output. If no error file is specified, Tidy writes messages
>   to the standard error. For command line options that expect a
>   numerical argument, a default is assumed if no meaningful value can be
>   found.

Comment: Thanks! The program shall do this over and over again by passing the string through tidy, just presenting the user with clean html. I did try that example I gave in my question, but it treats it like I'm giving it a file, and says it cannot open that file... I guess there must be some argument telling tidy that it's a string?

Comment: What are you writing your codes in? There seems to be different flavor of it in [Java](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html), [PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/241/tidying-up-your-html-with-php-5/), [Perl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ptidy/) etc.. If anything, it will give you more control.

Comment: I am writing my code in basic (Gambas). The language has the ability to do it like this:     

Shell "tidy some.file" To MyVar .   This will store tidy's output in MyVar, but instead of passing it a file, I want to pass it a string.

Comment: So, basically I am using the normal CLI version of tidy, just calling it from within my app.

Comment: I tried the CLI version and read through their doc, it looks like there is no way to pass in a string. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. For example:

```
$ tidy --indent yes < <(printf "%s\n" "<p>asdf</p>")
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 1 column 1 - Warning: inserting implicit <body>
line 1 column 1 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
Info: Document content looks like HTML5
Tidy found 3 warnings and 0 errors!

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content=
    "HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Mac OS X version 5.4.0">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      asdf
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```